# What would the output impedance of the circuit below be?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, circuit-design, impedance, feedback

[image]

My analysis is as follows, the auxiliary amplifier with input Vb is being used to sample the output current of the main amplifier (NMOS on the bottom) and return a voltage to its gate. So it is current-voltage feedback being used to gain boost which would improve the output impedance by a factor of 1+gmr0 of the auxiliary amplifier, so Rz=(1+gmr0)*r0_of_main_amp.

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: `Vb` ... did you mean to say `Vg`?

Comment: @jsotola, Vb in the figure-- which is the gate input to the NMOS on the top is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on VB.

If the lower transistor is kept in saturation, then if you add additional current at RZ, the the lower device (in saturation) sinks it ==> its VGS increases by deltaI/gm. This is the same as the change at RZ.

So a deltaI leads to a deltaV of deltaI/gm. ==> RZ = 1/gm.

Comment: Actually now I see your point, it's like using a wide-swing cascode load. However I am still trying to figure out where I am going wrong with my analysis of it from a feedback standpoint.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the resistance of each FET in series.  The sum can never less than the lower one with Vgs=Vds and Vg>Vt, so there is no gain in reducing both Rdson less than either one with this cascode when Vg > Vt.